# Does EF7 support EDMX approach?.How to use EF7 to execute stored procedure?

Tags: entity-framework, edmx, edmx-designer

Does EF7 support EDMX approach?.How to use EF7 to execute stored procedure?.
Any suggestion is appreciable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run stored procedures in Entity Framework 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28599404/how-to-run-stored-procedures-in-entity-framework-7)

Answer (score 4):

There is no EDMX support, but Database First Will Continue.[**Here**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn890367.aspx) you can find out more.

EF 7 will support multiple result sets in the future, but at this stage there is no support for them. You can track the Stored procedure support on this [**GIT issue**](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/245).

Hope this helps to you.

Answer (score 1):

EF Core, does not support EDMX, nor its preceding EF 6.x

In the other hand, it already supports stored procedures that returns result sets. The requirement is that the class this script will hydrate need to be declared as a DbSet in the DbContext.

Take a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35631903/raw-sql-query-without-dbset-entity-framework-core/35633596#35633596) for details.