# Interbase DDEX provider for visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, entity-framework-6, interbase

hi i'm working on creating entity framework DDEX provider for interbase db. i a'm following another opensource entity framework provider (Firebird) as a reference to my development. I have done necessary changes to [my project](https://github.com/Jayendra88/DDEXInterbase) and follo(https://github.com/cincuranet/FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient/blob/master/DDEX/readme.txt).

I have two issues.

1. When I try to add interbase database into server explorer I can see "Interbase data source"

[image: this image]

. But when I am trying to add entity data model (.edmx) it doesn't show interbase data source

[image: this image].

2. When I try to go further by selecting "Interbase data source" in server explorer it prompts an exception saying "Failure has occurred while loading a type"

I can't debug on this because this is a dll that is in GAC. I would appreciate if someone can help me to figure out this issue.

Comment: .edmx files are not supported going forward:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36864049/does-ef7-support-edmx-approach-how-to-use-ef7-to-execute-stored-procedure

Comment: You should not install in GAC, deploy via a VSIX instead, then you can do debugging

Comment: you need an interbase .net provider an register it in machine.config

Comment: is there any resources that explains the configuration of DDEX ?