# Entity Framework 7 Stored Procedure Result to Model

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, entity-framework-core, entities

I have a Model which is mapped to the database via EF7. All properties are identical to the mapped columns of the table.

Now I have a Stored Procedure, which returns some Joined Columns but the basis is still the mapped Model.

Here is my model(Entity) which is mapped to Table1 on my database.

`public partial class Table1
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public bool Column1{ get; set; }
        public int Column2 { get; set; }
        public int Column3 { get; set; }
        public int Column4 { get; set; }
        public int Column5 { get; set; }
}`

My StoredProcedure returns all of these columns and additionally a Column from another table, which contains additional information on this object.

So My StoredProcedure looks like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Table1_Select
    AS
        BEGIN
            SELECT  Column1,
                    Column2,
                    Column3,
                    Column4,
                    Column5,
                    Table2.JoinedColumn1
            FROM    Table1
            JOIN    Table2 on Table1.ID = Table2.ID_Table1
        END
```

My Idea was to just add a Property to the Model

```
public string JoinedColumn1 {get; set;}
```

This is working for executing the StoredProcedure, but it's not working as soon as I want to get one Entity with

```
MyContext.Table1.FirstOrDefault(t=>t.id == 1)
```

this always returns a Server Error 500 in Fiddler whereas the Stored Procedure Execution with "Table1.FromSql("Table1Select")" works fine.

Or do I have to decide whether to use StoredProcedures for my Model OR accessing Entities directly?

Any Best-Practices or solutions for this?

Many thanks in advance.
Nicn

Comment: Why do not the Store procedures included in the project which using Entity Framework Database  First  approach?

Comment: How to add StoredProcedures in Scaffold command? I only found [this link](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/wiki/Design-Meeting-Notes-(October-1,-2015)#table-selection-in-reverse-engineering) which says -t for tables or -s for schemas ...

Answer (score 0):

try this way,

```
var results = db.Database.SqlQuery<YourModel>("exec YourSPName [Optional Parameters]").ToList();
```

Comment: `return context.Table1.FromSql` is working fine when I add the joined Column as Property, however `context.Table1.ToList()` is not working anymore.

Comment: Model: `public partial class Table1
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public bool Column1{ get; set; }
        public int Column2 { get; set; }
        public int Column3 { get; set; }
        public int Column4 { get; set; }
        public int Column5 { get; set; } 
        public string JoinedColumn1 { get; set; }
}`

Working command:
`StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
 sql.Append("EXEC Table1_Select");
 return Table1.FromSql(sql.ToString()).ToList();`

Not working command:
`return context.Table1.ToList();`

or do you need the files?

Comment: it will be much better if you provide files.

Comment: you can find my testproject here: http://www.filedropper.com/testproject_1.
It's a tiny WebAPI, you may have to include your sql-server and create the Database if you need to test it with data. you can find the SP-Creation script in the root-folder of the zip file.

Comment: @nicn please check my latest answer.

Answer (score 0):

I read from a source as a solution use ADO.NET Connection Sample.

Parameters Sample

```
try
{
            SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter("Table1_Select", ConnectionString);
            adapt.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yourparameters", param);

            adapt.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            adapt.Fill(dt);
            adapt.Dispose();
            adapt = null;

            return dt;
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
throw ex
}
```

Don't Parameters Sample ;

```
try
{
    SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter("Table1_Select", ConnectionString);
    adapt.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    adapt.Fill(dt);
    adapt.Dispose();
    adapt = null;

    return dt;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

You get table columns set datatable and read dataTable values and set your class datatable values.

Read DataTable Sample :

```
 DataTable dt = YourGetDataTableFunction(val);
  DataRow dr = dt.Rows[0]; //index is zero
string Column1 = dr["column1"].ToString();
string Column2 =dr["column2"].ToString();
```

I hope it helps.

Other Question : [How to run stored procedures in Entity Framework Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28599404/how-to-run-stored-procedures-in-entity-framework-7)

Answer (score 0):

From your recent post,you said that you are using same model and getting error,so i would like to suggest that use [NOTMAPPED] before your pertcular declared
entity lets say,

`public int Column5 { get; set; }` 
which is only used while you are calling your SP,so write like,

```
[NotMapped]
public int Column5 { get; set; }
```

Comment: This is working for entities, but `.FromSql("exec SP_Name")` does not return this column now. Do I have to use Akin's way for storedProcedures then to get this column's value?

Comment: have you tried this? it might work for you.
var results = db.Database.SqlQuery<YourModel>("exec YourSPName [Optional Parameters]").ToList();

Comment: It seems that in 7.0.0-rc1-final FromSql has replaced SqlQuery and has to be against a DbSet. We will see in the team which way we will go and which cases may appear in our project. many thanks for your effort in this.

Comment: @nicn : it's my pleasure to work with you in this topic,as you said your team will decide that what will go and cases,so i would like to request you that if you find proper solution than also post in this page so other can solve from your updated answer.Thanks