# Mapping a class to a stored procedure resultset "Value cannot be null.Parameter name: entityType"

Tags: entity-framework-core

I am using `Entity Framework 7 RC1 Code First`.

I have the following code

```
var resultset = await _db.Employees.FromSql<Employee>("dbo.sp_GetEmployees @DeptId="+ deptId).ToListAsync();
```

this works and fetches the data correctly.

however I need to change the stored proc to contain other properties than employees are returning.

So I adjust the stored proc and create a custom class `EmployeeQuery` that inherits from Employee with the additional properties.

However  FromSql is a method on the `DbSet` of my `DBContext`

```
 public DbSet<Employee> Employees{ get; set; }
```

so I can do the same for `EmployeeQuery` by creating

```
 public DbSet<EmployeeQuery> EmployeeQueryItems{ get; set; }
```

and 
      var resultset = await _db.EmployeeQueryItems.FromSql("dbo.sp_GetEmployees @DeptId="+ deptId).ToListAsync();

however creating a `DBSet` property this tells Entity Framework to create the table in the database and it's simply just a query object. So I don't want to do the above.

However apparently you can use the `DbContext` Set Method  as mentioned in [github](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/1864) and in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28599404/how-to-run-stored-procedures-in-entity-framework-7)

so I change my code to
         var resultset= await _db.Set().FromSql("dbo.sp_GetEmployees @DeptId="+ deptId).ToListAsync();

However this gives me a runtime error

> ex = {"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: entityType"}

How do I get around this?

From this [gitbub issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/4227) it doesn't seem possible without creating a dummy table.

Is there not a way to tell EF to not create the table? Like a `NotMapped` attribute on the `DbSet`?

Answer (score 3):

I ran across this issue myself, and the only way I was able to resolve the problem was mapping a key for the POCO.

In a partial class along side the generated context, I override `OnModelCreating` and add:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ClassName>(entity => entity.HasKey(e => e.Id));
```

Seems to satisfy EntityFramework.

Comment: Can you expand on this please?

So In an MVC controller I may have a method returning something like this:

public JsonResult EmployeeUserRead()
{
    `var result = (from user in appContext.Users
                     join emp in context.Employees on user.Id equals emp.UserId
                      select new { user, emp }).ToList();

return Json(result);
}`

I do not see where a modelBuilder comes into play??