# EF Core, how to call stored procedure with input and output params?

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, entity-framework-core

In EF Core, with `dbContext`, how do you call a stored procedure with input AND an output param? I know the basic gyst is:

```
Set<blah>.FromSql("storedProcName @p0 = {0}, @p1 = {1}", p0, p1);
```

But, what do I put for "blah" since there is no entity, it's just a bool output... and how do I get said output?

EDIT: That question doesn't solve the issue.

DAMN... FINALLY got it working... you have to use the brace syntax and add the OUTPUT keyword on the last param.

```
SqlParameter paramOut = new SqlParameter("@p5", SqlDbType.Bit) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output };

        this.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("exec usp_xxx @p1={0}, @p2={1}, @p3={2}, @p4={3}, @p5={4}, @exist={5} OUTPUT",
            p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, paramOut);
```

Comment: isn't there the `Database` object off context?  Like `context.Database.SqlQuery("...");`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run stored procedures in Entity Framework Core?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28599404/how-to-run-stored-procedures-in-entity-framework-core)

Comment: @Jonesopolis -- hmm... ok, that might solve the blah issue :), but what about the out parameter? Doesn't seem like it accepts a SqlParameter object like the samples show.

Comment: @Eris, do you see anything there about OUT params?

Comment: @SledgeHammer The second answer shows how to create a standard SQLCommand object from the DBContext information, which allows you to use normal parameters and set `ParameterDirection.Output`

Comment: @Eris, trying to do: SqlParameter sql = new SqlParameter("@exist", System.Data.SqlDbType.Bit) { Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output };

   var v = this.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("xxx", p1, address, city, state, zip, sql); but I keep getting an exception saying "@exist" is missing.

Comment: @Eris... hmm... I was able to get it working with the "native" SqlCommand call, but not with the FromSql or ExecuteSqlCommand... seems like they don't wire up the params correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You could write a utility method like:

```
private static int ExecuteSqlCount(string statement, SqlParameter[] paramsSql)
{
    using (Entities dbContext = new Entities())
    {
        var total = dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<int>(statement, paramsSql).First();
        return total;
        }
    }
}
```

Assuming the stored procedure takes the two parameters as shown and returns an integer, it would be called like:

```
var parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();
string statement = "exec uspPersonAdd @personName = @name, @activeFlag = @active";
parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@name", person.PersonName));
parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@active", person.Active));
int id = ExecuteSqlCount(statement, parameters.ToArray());
```

Comment: The SP is using Set @exist = 1

Comment: Are you sure you are talking EF CORE? They don't have a .SqlQuery on the Database object.