# DbParameterCollection does not contain a definition for AddWithValue

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Getting above error on the last line of the following code. I'm using `EF Core 1.1`. Trying to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28612514/1232087) suggestion.

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Data.SqlClient; //Visual Studio had greyed out this line suggesting this as unnecessary.

var conn = _context.Database.GetDbConnection();

var cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = "MySproc";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MyParameter", 42);
```

Comment: You need to add the reference to System.Data.SqlClient

Comment: @H.Herzl I tried your suggestion - still the same error. Also when I added `System.Data.SqlClient` Visual Studio has greyed it out suggesting this using statement as unnecessary.

Comment: I think you need to cast your db connection to sql connection

Comment: @H.Herzl It works with your suggested casting - thanks.

Comment: You should also be aware of the performance implications of using `AddWithValue`. Rather than repeat them all, there is a good explanation of these in the accepted answer [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/195937/addwithvalue-performance-and-plan-cache-implications)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add reference for System.Data.SqlClient and cast your DbConnection instance to SqlConnection.

Comment: NOTE: this only applies for SQL Server. If you're using MySQL and therefore have a MySqlConnection object instead, you can't perform that cast.

Answer (score 18):

Here's the equivalent code using just the System.Data.Common APIs. (It can be used with any ADO.NET provider.)

```cs
var parameter = cmd.CreateParameter();
parameter.ParameterName = "@MyParameter";
parameter.Value = 42;

cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);
```

Comment: This answer doesn't have any relation with question, the question is about to use a method that allows add a parameter with name and value in same code line

Comment: @H.Herzl There is no such method available without casting to a more specific type. This code accomplishes the task without casting.

Comment: Great answer - exactly what I needed! This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @bricelam is this injection safe?

Comment: Yes. ADO.NET parameters are designed to prevent SQL injection.

Answer (score 1):

In dotnet core 3+ running command is broken. To fix it, change System.Data.SqlClient to Microsoft.Data.SqlClient