# EF Core 1.1 context.set() not found, how to call stored procedures?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

The method

```
dbContext.Set().FromSql("dbo.SomeSproc @Id = {0}, @Name = {1}", 45, "Ada");
```

of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28599404/how-to-run-stored-procedures-in-entity-framework-core) has been remove in entity framework 1.1.2 ?

[image][image]

The procedure do not return anything.
How can I call stroed procedures? (If I don't use the old ADO.NET way)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational** library.

To install it First, you need to see which version you need. Go to this [link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational/) and under Dependencies look for it.

For example, I had Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 1.1.2 so I use the version 1.1.2 of Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.

Then you can installed using the Package Manager.
Open the console in Visual Studio using the **Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Console** command

Paste the code to install the library in the PM console.

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational -Version 1.1.2
```