# The type or namespace name 'Relational' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore'

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

In an ASP.Net Core 1.1 web application, in VS 2017, I need to reference the package:
*Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational*
(this is in order to call stored procedures with result sets as described here:
[How to run stored procedures in Entity Framework Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28599404/how-to-run-stored-procedures-in-entity-framework-core))

When installing the package from PM console, with:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational
```

I get "Successfully installed 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational 1.1.2'"

But when I add the line:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational;
```

at the top of the file, the word "Relational" has a red squiggle under with the error:

> The type or namespace name 'Relational' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I isolated the problem to creating a new project of type "ASP.Net Core Web Application (.Net Framework)", selecting the template for an empty ASP.Net Core 1.1 project, then installing the above package. I still get the same error.
TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational` is *assembly*. There is no such *namespace* in EF Core.

The `FromSql` method is defined in the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` namespace, `RelationalQueryableExtensions` class, so all you need to get access to it is the typical

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
```

Comment: According to the StackOverflow post I linked to, in order to retrieve a typed result set from a stored procedure, I need to use: dbContext.Set() which is in the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational assembly. I _did_ install that assembly as  described in my question

Comment: That's correct. You need to install the **assembly**. By doing that it will bring up some additional methods in the aforementioned **namespace**. Btw, the answer from the link is not quite correct - there is not `Set()` method, the method is `Set<T>()` and `FromSql` is an extension method of `IQueryable<T>`.

Comment: I would suggest you reading the comments under the accepted answer you are referring to. Accepted and upvoted doesn't always mean working. Especially in EF Core where the things change with almost every build :(

Comment: Thanks Ivan, I think I've got it now. At the time of the post I got my info from, the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational assembly contained a namespace of the same name, under which was the method FromSql. In the latest version it only adds new classes to the namespace Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, and that's where FromSql is now.