# DOTNET 5.0.3 DBContext does not have FromSqlRaw method

Tags: mysql, .net, backend

I am trying to run a stored procedure on MySQL with the below code :

```
List<SqlParameter> parms = new List<SqlParameter> {
                    new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@word", Value = word }
                };
                Object result = _context.History.FromSqlRaw<HistoryDM>("EXEC GETHISTORY", parms.ToArray());
                if (result != null)
                {
                    retval = (IEnumerable<HistoryDM>)result;
                }
```

The error I get is :
'DbSet' does not contain a definition for 'FromSqlRaw' and no accessible extension method 'FromSqlRaw' accepting a first argument of type 'DbSet' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). In fact I don't see any From* methods on that context.

I have no clue what is happening here. after some research, I also added the package "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" but it did not have remove the error.

Thanks for your help in advance,
UU

Comment: Looks like an [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalqueryableextensions.fromsqlraw?view=efcore-5.0)  Did you add the package and the [correct using statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51017703/error-cs1061-dbsett-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-fromsql-and-no-exte)?

Comment: I would have sworn that I had "using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;" but reality was different :) Thanks @Mohammed. Now this throws a MySqlException "Only MySQL parameter objects may be stored". Any clue :             if (word != null && !word.Equals(""))
            {
                var param = new SqlParameter("@word", word);
                var result = _context.History.FromSqlRaw("CALL GETHISTORY @word", param).ToList();
                if (result != null)
                {
                    retval = (IEnumerable<HistoryDM>)result;
                }
            }

Comment: I created a new thread here for the follow-up issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67190000/calling-mysql-stored-procedure-from-net-db-context-throws-only-mysqlparameter- @Muhammed can I credit you for your answer ?