# Calling MySQL Stored Procedure from .NET DB Context throws "Only MySqlParameter objects may be stored'"

Tags: mysql, .net, dbcontext

I am using .NET Core 5 DBContext to access MYSQL Stored procedure to get results with the below code :

```
var param = new SqlParameter("@word", word);
            var result = _context.History.FromSqlRaw("EXEC GETHISTORY @word", param).ToList();
            if (result != null)
            {
                retval = (IEnumerable<HistoryDM>)result;
            }
```

Yet it throws the below exception,

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'Only MySqlParameter objects may be stored'

So, what is the error trying to tell me and how can I fix it ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK, looks like when one knows it it is relatively simple :

```
Object result = _context.History.FromSqlInterpolated($"CALL ADDHISTORY ({word})").ToList();
```

So, both CALL is used (instead of EXEC) and parentheses around the parameter, which is also like the MySQL native call. No black magic here.

Thanks a lot for your support @Marc !!

Answer (score 1):

`SqlParameter` is for SqlClient, i.e. SQL Server. You want a `new MySqlParameter` (the connection, command, parameter and reader types are all provider-specific). Or better: ask the connection to create the parameter, or use a tool that will deal with the ADO.NET internals for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Mark ! I also saw that pattern but I had an "internal rejection" to it as it imposes a DB flavor into the code, isn't there a better way to abstract this ?

Comment: @GeoSystems yes: you can ask the command to create the parameter (`DbCommand.CreateParameter`), or you can use a tool that does it for you; personally I'd use Dapper for this, but I see you're using EF; in that case, perhaps your best bet is to use `FromSqlInterpolated`, i.e. `.History.FromSqlInterpolated($"EXEC GETHISTORY {word}").ToList()`,

Comment: Thanks @Mark ! Q1: Why do you use EXEC ? MySQL uses "CALL" in its native environment, would that translate to EXEC in .NET? Q2) I get an error when I use as parameter 'test' : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'EXEC GETHISTORY 'test'' at line 1'. Any advice on that ?

Comment: @GeoSystems "Why do you use EXEC" - I literally copy/pasted that from the question

Comment: Any ideas on the pending error ?  "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use."

Comment: @GeoSystems all Incan say there is "fix your syntax" - I'm not a mysql person, I just know the ado.net API