# Call stored procedure in asp.net MVC 5 for existing database and stored procedure in SQL server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have the existing database with tables, views and stored procedures in SQL Server. I am looking for ways to call and execute this stored procedures in either ASP.NET MVC 5 web application or ASP.NET core. I saw various ways using Entity framework and ADO.net on the internet, but always got somewhere struck. Can someone please tell me the best way to deal this scenario. Also, note I need to use the existing stored procedure as whole business logic is already done in stored procedures.My completely new to ASP.NET so any suggestions regarding what technology, frameworks or tools to use will be a great help.

Comment: Too broad a question...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run stored procedures in Entity Framework Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28599404/how-to-run-stored-procedures-in-entity-framework-core)