# Entity Framework Core 2.0 call stored procedure

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

How can I call a stored procedure using Entity Framework Core 2.0? Asp.net core 2.0 site in C#

Comment: What have you tried? For example have you tried googling this? Because you'll get a lot of results. Please try something and come back with a specific question.

Comment: I have googled and tried several option but most of the google stuff refers to entity core 1.0 and not 2.0 With members of the data context not there for it.

Comment: Can you post the code you tried and post the error message you get from it

Comment: I am not getting an error as I cant find a syntax for calls off the db context to even try that will combine with the properties available.

Comment: hmmm.. does this link help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28599404/how-to-run-stored-procedures-in-entity-framework-core

Comment: Thanks. It did.  Was missing the namespace reference to Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore in the class.  Once there all the functions i expected to see.

Answer (score 2):

csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

program.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace EfExperiment
{
    class Program
    {
        public class Record
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public DateTime Date { get; set; }
            public decimal Value { get; set; }
        }

        public class RecordsDbContext : DbContext
        {
            public DbSet<Record> Records { get; set; }

            public List<Record> RecordsByDateRange(DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate)
            {
                var fromDateParam = new SqlParameter("fromDate", fromDate);
                var toDateParam = new SqlParameter("toDate", toDate);

                return Records
                    .FromSql("EXECUTE dbo.RecordsByDateRange @fromDate, @toDate", fromDateParam, toDateParam)
                    .ToList();
            }

            protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
            {
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=RecordsDb;Trusted_Connection=True;");
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var dbc = new RecordsDbContext())
            {
                var records = dbc.RecordsByDateRange(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1), DateTime.Now);
                Console.WriteLine($"{records.Count} records loaded");

                foreach (var record in records)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"[{record.Id}] [{record.Date}] {record.Value}");
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press <enter>");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```