# Calling a simple stored procedure in EF core 3.1

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have a very simple stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ClearIterations]
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    delete from iterations
END
GO
```

When calling it from EF it is not called. I get no errors:

```
public void ClearIterations()
{
    this.Iterations.FromSqlRaw("ClearIterations").IgnoreQueryFilters();
}
```

Any pointers? I found the sample above on another thread in here that where the code above is the answer. It seems kind of strange I have to call this this.Iterations to call a SP.

Comment: [Database.ExecuteSqlRaw](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions.executesqlraw?view=efcore-3.1)

Comment: That worked! Can you add an answer?

Comment: For simplest and most complete answer, check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75465142/8644294

Answer (score 8, accepted):

EF Core 3.x+ provides two raw SQL sets of methods - `FromSql` and `ExecuteSql`, both with `Raw` / `Interpolated` and `Async` versions.

The former are used for *querying*. They return `IQueryable<T>`, allow query composition and as any LINQ query are not executed until the result is enumerated.

While the later is used to immediately execute arbitrary SQL (DDL, DML, batch etc.). They are EF Core equivalent of ADO.NET `ExecuteNonQuery` and return the records affected. Output (or input/output) primitive value parameters can be used to obtain the results.

Shortly, `ExecuteSql` methods are what you are seeking for. With your example, [ExecuteSqlRaw](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions.executesqlraw?view=efcore-3.1), e.g. (assuming this is method in your `DbContext` derived class):

```
public void ClearIterations()
{
    this.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("ClearIterations");
}
```

Comment: How do I get the result from `Select GetDate()` with `ExecuteSqlRaw`?

Comment: @OldGeezer The same way you would in ADO.NET `DbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery` - using parameters. Of course you would need something like "select $someOutParam = GetDate()" rather than just "select". If you really want to execute query, then `FromSql` is the only way with all associated drawbacks.

Comment: Thanks. I did it using https://stackoverflow.com/a/45262161/936293. Surprised that it requires so many lines of code just for a one-line statement.

Comment: @OldGeezer  It's not surprising because that's actually the old good ADO.NET way. The only EF Core code is `Database.GetDbConnection()` which gives you the configured `DbConnection` object which EF Core is using internally, but nothing more than that.

Answer (score 2):

```
//Interface
public interface IRepository
{
    Task AddQualification(int userId, string qualification);
}
```

Repository class implementing your interface remember to register your interface in your startup class ConfigureServices services.AddScoped<IRepository, Repository>()

```
public class Repository : IRepository
{
    public async Task AddQualification(int userId, string qualification)
    {
        await appDbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync("InsertQualification {0}, {1}", userId, qualification);
    }
}
```

Constructor injection of the interface, then call the method

```
public async Task OnPost()
{
    await _repository.AddQualification(1, "English A-Level");
}
```

SQL Stored Procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertQualification 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @UserID int, 
    @Qualification varchar(255)

AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO dbo.UserQualifications (UserID, Qualification)
    VALUES (@UserID, @Qualification)

END
GO
```

Comment: Please post you code as **text** - formatted as a code block (surround with two rows each of three backticks: ```).