# Is there any possible ways to return the results generated through a stored procedure using Entity Framework Core in .net Core MVC..?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am developing a .net core application in the database first approach. Along with that i am using Microsoft SQL Server for my database process. I am trying to return the results generated in the stored procedure to the application using entity framework core but, i'm unable to find a way. Is there any possible ways to do it..?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run stored procedures in Entity Framework Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28599404/how-to-run-stored-procedures-in-entity-framework-core)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EF Core provides the following methods to execute a stored procedure:

1. Using `DbSet<TEntity>.FromSql()`

   Suppose there have a `GetStudents` stored procedure. You can execute SP using FromSql
   method in EF Core in the same way as above, as shown below.

   ```
    var context = new SchoolContext(); 

    var students = context.Students.FromSql("GetStudents 'Bill'").ToList();
   ```
2. Using `DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand()`

   Supposer this have a `CreateStudents` stored procedure to insert students. Then, you could use the following code to call the SP.

   ```
   var context = new SchoolContext(); 

   context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("CreateStudents @p0, @p1", parameters: new[] { "Bill", "Gates" });
   ```

More detail information, please check the article:[Working with Stored Procedure in Entity Framework Core](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/working-with-stored-procedure-in-ef-core.aspx). Besides, you could also use the [Raw SQL Queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql) to execute the stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

EF Core documentation: [Querying from Raw SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql)
Include an entity type in your EF model that matches the stored procedure output columns.