# EF Core ExecuteReader or ExecuteScalar - Stored Procedure Incorrect parameter but no exception

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I'm using **.Net EF Core 3.1.5**, I need to call an existing SQL Server stored procedure with parameters.

The procedure is executing fine and the parameter I pass in are working.

**I'm having an issue whereby no warning or errors are being caught from SQL Server.** My stored procedure is `'GetProcessEvents'` which takes parameter  @runId. If I change  @runId to be  @xxxxxId in my C# the stored procedure will not run but no error will be returned to my C#.

I've tried return `Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());` and as in the code below 'ExecuteReader' but neither work. Even if I put a 'select 100/0' in the stored procedure no exception is returned - If I run the procedure directly in SQL Server Management Studio I get ***"Msg 8134, Level 16, State 1, Line 1. Divide by zero error encountered.***" which I would expect as an exception in C#.

```
try
{
    if (sqlConn == null)
        return 0;

    DbCommand cmd = _context.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand();

    cmd.CommandText = "GetProcessEvents";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@runId", runId));

    if (cmd.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        cmd.Connection.Open();

    var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if (reader.HasRows) // I've tried with and without this if
    {
        while (reader.Read())
            return reader.GetInt32(0);
    }
    return runId;
}
catch (SqlException sqle)
{
    throw sqle; // No exception ever caught
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    throw e;
}
```

Do I need to try one of the other solutions in [This StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28599404/how-to-run-stored-procedures-in-entity-framework-core) - Although I tried `FromSql` and Visual Studio indicates it's obsolete.

Please help. Many thanks!

Also, In case this adds anything, I'm using SignalR successfully to retrieve SQL Server warning (< less than severity 10 - so not error) events (SQL: `RAISERROR ( '1' ,0, 10) WITH NOWAIT`) raised from the stored procedure which fires back progress events as the possibly long running procedure is executing. This is working fine and the events are being received by C# from SQL Server.
**Please Note:** I have tried the above issue with and without wiring up the code below.

```
sqlConn.FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors = true;

// Number of times the stored procedure(s) will return notifications to the Client
if (percentageNotifications == null)
    percentageNotifications = 10;

// Wire up delegate to SQL Server connection
sqlConn.InfoMessage += delegate (object sender, SqlInfoMessageEventArgs e)
{
    // Fire notification to SignalR Hub and anwards to client on RAISERROR (severity <10: just a message) from Sql Server
    NotificationsComplete++;
    _contextHub.Clients.All.SendAsync("UpdateProgressBar", taskId, ((100 / percentageNotifications) * NotificationsComplete).ToString());
};
```

Comment: We do not see the declaration of "runId" to check whether it's the right type. Also, maybe try the parameters.AddWithValue overload

Comment: Perhaps you need to consume all result sets and messages. See [this article](https://www.dbdelta.com/the-curious-case-of-undetected-sql-exceptions/).