# Stored procedure in entity framework core returning multiple resultsets

Tags: c#, database, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

How can I execute the stored procedure from the database using entity framework core and return multiple resultsets? This is my context class and stored procedure which I want to call. I do not want to use ADO.Net to call the stored procedure.

```
public partial class MAPContext : DbContext
    {
        IConfiguration _configuration;
        public EPAContext()
        {
        }

        public EPAContext(DbContextOptions<MAPContext > options, IConfiguration configuration)
            : base(options)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Local> Locals { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Site> Sites { get; set; }
 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Local>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasNoKey();

                entity.ToTable("Local");

                entity.Property(e => e.Id)
                    .HasMaxLength(255)
                    .HasColumnName("ID");

                entity.Property(e => e.Idx)
                    .HasMaxLength(255)
                    .HasColumnName("idx");

                entity.Property(e => e.Loc)
                    .HasMaxLength(255)
                    .HasColumnName("loc");

                entity.Property(e => e.Price).HasColumnName("price");

                entity.Property(e => e.Date)
                    .HasColumnType("datetime")
                    .HasColumnName("date");
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<Site>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(e => e.Idx)
                    .HasName("Site_PK");

                entity.ToTable("SITEs");

                entity.Property(e => e.Idx)
                    .HasColumnName("idx")
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("(newid())");

                entity.Property(e => e.Cdate)
                    .HasColumnType("datetime")
                    .HasColumnName("cdate")
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("(getdate())");

                entity.Property(e => e.Color)
                    .HasMaxLength(50)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .HasColumnName("color");

                entity.Property(e => e.Direct)
                    .HasMaxLength(50)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .HasColumnName("direct");

                entity.Property(e => e.Note)
                    .HasColumnType("text")
                    .HasColumnName("NOTE");

                entity.Property(e => e.Date)
                    .HasColumnType("datetime")
                    .HasColumnName("date")
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("(getdate())");

            });
 OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
        }

        partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
}
```

This is a Stored Procedure that I created in the database and want to call using entity framework core

```
CREATE STORED PROCEDURE [dbo.sp_MapDetail]
@Id uniqueIdentifier
AS
    SELECT * FROM dbo.Map WHERE id = @Id
    SELECT * FROM dbo.Sites WHERE id = @Id
    SELECT dbo.Bridge.idx, dbo.Bridge.name, dbo.Bridge.site, dbo.Bridge.description, dbo.Bridge.date, 
    dbo.Bridge.user FROM dbo.Bldgs INNER JOIN dbo.Sites ON 
    dbo.Bridge.site = dbo.Sites.idx AND dbo.Sites.id = @Id
```

Comment: You need to create a class that will represent the results your stored procedure is returning; looks like it will be a class that has a collection of  `Map`, `Sites`, and `BuildingSite`. Then call your stored procedure [as shown here](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/working-with-stored-procedure-in-ef-core.aspx). You may also check out [this](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/1864) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28599404/how-to-run-stored-procedures-in-entity-framework-core).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that with EF Core, you will have to use ADO.NET, SqlDataReader.GetNextResult.

https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.nextresult