# How to call stored procedure in .net 6 using EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I have a procedure I need to call it from my code using `EFCore`

Below is my procedure structure

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[BusinessOrders]  
(
    @StatusID INT ,
    @BusinessBranchID INT,
    @LangID INT ,
    @PurchasedOn NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
    @Search NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @PageSize INT,
    @PageNo INT 
)
AS
BEGIN

END
```

This is my code function

```
public IEnumerable<BusinessOrderEntity.BODB> GetBusinessOrders(int StatusID, int BusinessBranchID, int LangID, string PurchasedOn = "", string Search = "", int PageSize = 10, int PageNo = 1)
{
    // here need to call procedure.
}
```

I've find different solution but it does not working with my context class

Answer (score 2):

You can use [FromSqlInterpolated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalqueryableextensions.fromsqlinterpolated?view=efcore-6.0) method.

```
context.BODB.FromSqlInterpolated(
    $"[dbo].[BusinessOrders] {statusId}, {businessBranchId}, {langId}, {purchasedOn}, {search}, {pageSize}, {pageNo}");
```

See [SQL Queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/sql-queries) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

EF Core supports the old style for calling stored procedures:

```
private async Task ExecuteStoredProc()
{
    DbCommand cmd = _context.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand();

    cmd.CommandText = "dbo.sp_DoSomething";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@firstName", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = "Steve" });
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@lastName", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = "Smith" });

    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", SqlDbType.BigInt) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output });

    if (cmd.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        cmd.Connection.Open();
    }

    await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();

    long id = (long)cmd.Parameters["@Id"].Value;
}
```

You can check similar questions here:

- [How to run stored procedures in Entity Framework Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28599404/how-to-run-stored-procedures-in-entity-framework-core)
- [How do I call stored procedures in EF Core 6 using named parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71685267/how-do-i-call-stored-procedures-in-ef-core-6-using-named-parameters)

Comment: I would argue that `DbCommand` should be disposed.