# C# Entity Framework Core : how to execute stored procedure and get a list of custom data?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am trying to call a stored procedure in C# with EF Core. Just returning custom result set which is not linked to any entity.

But I am getting an error:

> Cannot create a DbSet for 'ExCoResponse' because this type is not included in the model for the context.

Here is my method:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<ExCoResponse>> UpdateAndGetExcoUsers()
{
    return await _context
                     .Query<ExCoResponse>()
                     .FromSql("[dbo].[UsersUpdateExcoDetail]")
                     .ToListAsync();
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Raw SQL Query without DbSet - Entity Framework Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35631903/raw-sql-query-without-dbset-entity-framework-core)

Comment: Entity framework core doesn't support mapping to arbitrary types. You must define the result as either a query type or an entity type.

Comment: How to define a query type? can you please provide me some example? Thanks

Comment: Its in that link.

Comment: I get error saying 'DbSet<entity>' does not contain definition for ''FromSqlRaw'

Comment: Install EF Core Power Tools VS extension and get it to generate your context instead. It includes ability to generate for stored procedures, functions , views etc

Comment: For simplest and most complete answer, check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75465142/8644294

Answer (score 0):

Since i am using Core 2.1
Following worked for me:

```
public DbQuery<ExcoUser> ExcoUsers { get; set; }

        var result = await _context
            .ExcoUsers.FromSql<ExcoUser>("EXEC [dbo].[UsersUpdateExcoDetail]")
            .ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

### **dot net core 3.0+**

1-  Install Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational package

2 - Add Entity and configuration to DbContext Model

```
public class ApplicationDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<ExCoResponse> ExCoResponses { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ExCoResponse>().HasNoKey();
    } // end OnModelCreating
} // end ApplicationDBContext
```

3-  use this query. **be careful have used Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;**

```
    var result = dBContext
            .Set<ExCoResponse>()
            .FromSqlRaw("exec [dbo].[UsersUpdateExcoDetail]").ToList();
```