# How to call stored procedure in Clean Architecture

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6, dbcontext, clean-architecture

I'm trying to understand Clean Architecture from Jason Taylor. Can anyone help to call a stored procedure?

Here is the link to his code repository

https://github.com/jasontaylordev/NorthwindTraders

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possibly a duplicate question of https://stackoverflow.com/a/28612514/2859272

Comment: Hi @JakeMc Its not duplicate ,as FromSQL doesnot appear. but it was helpful

but I have used the old traditional way to in Entity to call the stored procedure

DBCommand cmd = this.database.GetDbConnection.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "SPName";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter (....));
if(cmd.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
{
 cmd.Connection.Open();
}

cmd.ExecuteReader();

Comment: This question is too broad. Also, I don't see how the way a stored procedure is called using EF6 is depends on which application architecture is used.