# How to use just the stored procedures of an existing database through Entity Framework Core without creating table schema objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am still learning Entity Framework Core. I have already created a data context object and created a SQL database using the code-first approach.

Now I want to display data from a pre-existing SQL database. This pre-existing database has several tables and most of the business logic is written in stored procedures.

Is it possible to create another DB context object and use only the stored procedures from it without creating table schema objects?

Comment: Not really much point using an ORM if you're only using procedures

Comment: Yes, you can  do this with EF Core Power Tools

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of EF Core is to have Models representing any data you store or retrieve from the database. Since a stored procedure can retrieve information, you will want a class with defined properties that match the result of that stored procedure.

How to do this can be found in the Stack Overflow article found here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44244738/5636865